# How to make a JTextArea moving the scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am working with Java Swing and I have put a JTextArea in a JScrollBar. What I want is the scrollbar to follow the data.
For a example i want to write in the JTextArea the output of a for(;;) so i can see the latest (newest) values.
 How could I do that?

EDIT: I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: "I have a textarea in a scrollbar"  Did you mean a `JTextArea` in a **`JScrollPane`**?  Please be as clear and exact as possible, to save those reading having to guess what you mean.

Comment: scroll bar to follow the data.. What do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson @harishtps I have edited the question. As i say above i want to see the newest values and not to stop and i have to scroll down to see the data.

Comment: 1) If you are adding the component to a **`JScrollBar`**, then first thing is to change that to a **`JScrollPane`** as used by both Harry and me.  2) I still do not understand whether you have tried the code I posted, or if the problem is solved.  Did you?  Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/)

Comment: Thanks.  From your article, it seems my example only works (presuming it works at all) 'by accident'!

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AutoScrollTextArea {

    static String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "
        +"consectetur adipiscing elit. "
        +"Integer vestibulum metus id elit malesuada mattis. "
        +"Aliquam non rutrum justo. Morbi eleifend nisi ut "
        +"turpis commodo nec ultricies arcu vehicula. "
        +"Donec varius neque at nunc pellentesque tincidunt. "
        +"Phasellus sed ante ut tortor fermentum posuere sed "
        +"sit amet tortor. Sed cursus magna a lacus mattis eleifend. "
        +"Aliquam congue faucibus purus vel commodo. "
        +"Fusce rutrum consectetur nibh nec facilisis. ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
                final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10,60);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textArea.setLineWrap(true);
                textArea.setEnabled(false);
                gui.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JButton button = new JButton("Add Text");
                button.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        textArea.append(text);
                        textArea.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                        textArea.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    }
                } );
                gui.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

( It happens automatically ;)

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using JTextArea in JScrollPane then following should work:

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
area.setLineWrap(true);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);
```